# Table Row Spacing

Tags: tables

I created a table in LaTex using TeXstudio and cannot properly horizontally space the content within the last column.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[width=5.25in, height=8.00in, left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{2cm} | m{1.491cm} | c | c | m{1.4cm} | }
\hline
& \centering{Front} & Near-front & Central & \hspace{1.25ex}Back\\
\hline
\centering Close & \centering 〈ii〉 [i]&  &  &\\[5mm]
\hline
\centering Near-close &  & \centering 〈e〉 [ɪ] &  & \\[5mm]
\hline
\centering Mid & \centering 〈a〉 [e̞] &  &  & 〈y〉 [o̞]\\[5mm]
\hline
\centering Open-mid & \centering 〈i〉 [ɛ] & & 〈o〉 [ɞ] &\\[5mm]
\hline
\centering Open & \centering 〈ee | u〉 [ɶ] & & \centering 〈ȧ〉 [ä] &\\[10mm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

As you can see, the "Back" column is giving me issues. Without the `\hspace{1.25ex}` the word becomes no longer centered and applying`\centering` to the word returns an error.

Also, although I have `m{1.4cm}` for middle alignment in the last column, it seems to ignore it completely.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong since middle alignment and `\centering` have worked in the other columns.

Comment: Please make your code a compilable unit (`\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`). Avoid unnecessarily breaking example code into parts. Also, if the problem is not particularly about a font, consider making the example compilable for more people by not introducing a font dependency.

Comment: @mvkorpel Ok, I think I did what you said. Hope that helps?

Comment: I donot have any problem with current TeXLive 2014

Comment: Same here , It is compiling perfectly without any issue, check for yourself here https://www.writelatex.com/1227127ncydcc#/2959720/

Comment: @Nishant the "<y> [o]" still is neither centered nor middle aligned. I tried to use `centering` before it, but that gives a compiling error: https://www.writelatex.com/1227127ncydcc

Comment: Which font do you use? With Latin Modern, some symbols do not display.

Comment: @Bernard I use Charis SIL (using XeLaTeX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose two variants (aesthetically slighly different),  based on the `makecell` package, that allows for line breakss in cells and thick horizontal lines in tables, `cellspace` to have a greater vertical height of cell while keeping vertical centring of their contents (which the use of `\arraystretch` cannot do) and `tabularx` to have the 4 last cells of equal width.

There were warnings from the geometry package, so I simplified options (width and height were incompatible with the margins).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,onecolumn]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}
\def\thickvrule{\vrule width1pt}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[hmargin=0.50in, vmargin=0.25in]{geometry}%width=5.25in, height=8.00in,

\begin{document}

{\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\thickvrule}Sl!{\thickvrule}*{3}{X|}X!{\thickvrule}}%{ | *{5}{S{m{2cm}}|} }%Sc
\Xcline{2-5}{1pt}
\multicolumn{1}{Sl!{\thickvrule}}{\strut} & Front & Near-front & Central & Back \\
\Xhline{1pt}
 Close & 〈ii〉 [i]& & &\\
\hline
 Near-close & & 〈e〉 [ɪ] & & \\
\hline
 Mid & 〈a〉 [e̞] & & & 〈y〉 [o̞]\\
\hline
Open-mid & 〈i〉 [ɛ] & & 〈o〉 [ɞ] &\\
\hline
 Open & \makecell{ 〈ee | u〉 \cr [ɶ]} & & 〈ȧ〉 [ä] &\\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}\\[1cm]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Sl!{\thickvrule}*{3}{X|}X!{\thickvrule}}%
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ Front} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Near-front} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Central }& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Back} \\[3pt]
\Xcline{2-5}{1pt}
 Close & 〈ii〉 [i]& & &\\
\cline{2-5}
 Near-close & & 〈e〉 [ɪ] & & \\
\cline{2-5}
 Mid & 〈a〉 [e̞] & & & 〈y〉 [o̞]\\
\cline{2-5}
Open-mid & 〈i〉 [ɛ] & & 〈o〉 [ɞ] &\\
\cline{2-5}
 Open &\makecell{〈ee | u〉 \cr [ɶ]} & & 〈ȧ〉 [ä] &\\[-1pt]
\Xcline{2-5}{1pt}
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a new column definition to get the cells centered:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[width=5.25in, height=8.00in, left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{2cm} | M{1.491cm} | c | c | M{1.4cm} | @{}M{0pt} @{}}
\hline
& Front & Near-front & Central & Back\\
\hline
Close &  〈ii〉 [i]&  &  &\\[5mm]
\hline
Near-close &  &  〈e〉 [ɪ] &  & \\[5mm]
\hline
Mid & 〈a〉 [e̞] &  &  & 〈y〉 [o̞]\\[5mm]
\hline
Open-mid &  〈i〉 [ɛ] & & 〈o〉 [ɞ] &\\[5mm]
\hline
Open &  〈ee | u〉 [ɶ] & & 〈ȧ〉 [ä] &\\[10mm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems a lot cleaner, but the "〈y〉 [o̞]" is not middle aligned (although *shouldn't*  the `m{1.4cm}` make it middle aligned?) :\

Comment: that's a known issue of `tabular` Use an additional _empty_ column.

Comment: This still doesn't appear to fix the problem https://www.writelatex.com/1227127ncydcc or am I being dumb?

Comment: I edited the source